# JavaFX: If node equals node

Tags: java, javafx, equals

I have a simple JavaFX program like this:
[image: Layout]

When I hit the first button it puts content1 in the right side of the split screen. When I hit button2 it puts content2 on the right (behaving like it should).

But when there is an TextField in for example content2 and I click button2 again, it resets.
How can I check if I am already in content2?

Controller.java:

```
@FXML private SplitPane splitpane;
@FXML private Node content;


@FXML
public void initialize() {
    changeContent(new ContentA());
}



@FXML
public void onMenuClickA(ActionEvent event) {
    changeContent(new ContentA());
}
@FXML
public void onMenuClickB(ActionEvent event) {
    changeContent(new ContentB());
}




private void changeContent(Node node) {
    if (node.equals(content)) {        // <---- Not working
        System.out.println("Same");
    }
    List<Node> splitpaneItems = splitpane.getItems();
    splitpaneItems.set(splitpaneItems.indexOf(content), node);
    content = node;
}
```

ContentA.java:

```
public class ContentA extends HBox {

public ContentA() {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/contents/Test1.fxml"));

    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Preload them both in the `initialize()` method and save them to instance variables. Then you don't need to reload the FXML each time and you won't reset them.

Comment: Or, disable each button after it's pressed, and enable the button that wasn't pressed.

Comment: Neither the `Node` class, nor any of its subclasses, override `Object#equals(Object)` which means using `node.equals(otherNode)` is the same as `node == otherNode`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for your answer! I preloaded them in `initialize()` and it works like a charm! Now users can also switch tabs and keep their progress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions, depending on the exact behavior you want.

If you **never** want to reset the individual components, just preload them in the `initialize()` method, and save them to instance variables:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML private SplitPane splitpane;

    private ContentA contentA ;
    private ContentB contentB ; 

    private int contentIndex ;        

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        contentA = new ContentA();
        contentB = new ContentB();
        contentIndex = splitPane.getItems().size() ;
        splitPane.getItems().set(contentIndex, contentA);
    }



    @FXML
    public void onMenuClickA(ActionEvent event) {
        changeContent(contentA);
    }
    @FXML
    public void onMenuClickB(ActionEvent event) {
        changeContent(contentB);
    }

    private void changeContent(Node node) {
        splitpaneItems.set(contentIndex, node);
    }

}
```

On the other hand, if you want to "reset" the content when you load them, but want to prevent the user from reloading the current content, you could just disable the most recently pressed button:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML private SplitPane splitpane;
    @FXML private Button buttonA ;
    @FXML private Button buttonB ;

    private int contentIndex ;        


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        buttonA.setDisable(true);
        contentIndex = splitPane.getItems().size() ;
        changeContent(new ContentA()); 
    }



    @FXML
    public void onMenuClickA(ActionEvent event) {
        buttonA.setDisable(true);
        buttonB.setDisable(false);
        changeContent(new ContentA());
    }
    @FXML
    public void onMenuClickB(ActionEvent event) {
        buttonA.setDisable(false);
        buttonB.setDisable(true);
        changeContent(new ContentB());
    }




    private void changeContent(Node node) {
        splitpaneItems.set(splitpaneItems.indexOf(content), node);
    }

}
```

Finally, if you want to be able to control different behavior for different content (e.g. always reload content A, never reload content B), you need to use a variable to keep track of the state of the content. An `enum` works well for this:

```
public class Controller {

    private ContentB contentB  ;


    public enum Content {
        A(() -> new ContentA()),
        B(() -> contentB) ;


        private final Supplier<Node> nodeLoader ;

        Content(Supplier<Node> nodeLoader) {
            this.nodeLoader = nodeLoader ;
        }

        public Node getContent() {
            return nodeLoader.get();
        }
    }

    private Content currentContent ; 


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        contentB = new ContentB();

        contentIndex = splitPane.getItems().size() ;
        changeContent(Content.A);
    }



    @FXML
    public void onMenuClickA(ActionEvent event) {
        changeContent(Content.A);
    }
    @FXML
    public void onMenuClickB(ActionEvent event) {
        changeContent(Content.B);
    }

    private void changeContent(Content content) {
        this.currentContent = content ;
        splitpaneItems.set(contentIndex, content.getContent());
    }

}
```